# OSM: плавное перемещение маркера

Tags: карты, openstreetmap, leafletjs

В своем проекте использую карты OSM. На карте показываются маркеры. Раз в 30 секунд идет запрос до сервера, получаются новые координаты точек и надо их переместить. Сейчас все работает через `setLatLng()`, но надо сделать плавное перемещение.

Пробовал сделать через `slideTo()`, но тогда маркер просто по линии перемещается по карте, а мне надо что бы он перемещался по маршруту.

Подскажите, если кто то делал, что можно использовать.

P.S. С картами работаю через Leaflet

Comment: По какому то определенному маршруту или ещё надо по графу искать оптимальный?

Comment: маршрута нет, просто перемещение. но не просто по прямой, а как бы по дороге. скажем, gps трекер

Comment: то есть, не важно по какой, главное, что бы по дороге, а не по домах)

Comment: это сильно усложняет задачу, она у вас распадается на 2, поиск пути на графе, и потом интерполяция

Comment: то есть, нет возможности плавно переместить маркер с точки А в точку Б? координаты точек известны

Comment: Это вполне решаемая задача, но надо ещё получить граф дорог

Comment: то есть? у использую routing machine для построения маршрутов. это можно как то использовать?